# layout_weight changes image dimensions

Tags: android, android-layout

Basically I have ImageView in one of Linear layouts, when weights is set on each of my layouts gets resized, same goes with ImageView in layout. Problem is - only height that actually changes width is left the same.

Why it's a problem? I have customView and I need to place it on the cup so it requires x,y cordinates of cup and it's size (width and height). Now I am getting different widths with different screen sizes.

Layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlmainContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/cup1_r" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Archie.bpgc solution (setting layout_height="0dp") doesn't help. Setting few more images and they all are with unproportional widths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/cup1_r" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/cup1_r" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivCup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/cup1_r" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/cup1_r" />

    </LinearLayout>    

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `layout_height = 0dp` while setting the weight. Its an optimization too.

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

for both the LinearLayouts.

And also you don't need the `RelativeLayout` since you only have a single `ImageView` in the 1st `LinearLayout`

Comment: @user2060190 looks like i misunderstood the question. You want your `ImageViews` to be of **equal height** right?(what i could make out from your code). If you want the width also to be same for all the images remove `wrap_content` and set some value or `fill_parent`.